# Gnome Screen Lock setting not respected in Ubuntu 17.10 when using gnome-session

Tags: gnome, suspend, 17.10

If you're running the default Gnome session in Ubuntu 17.10 (by installing it with `sudo apt install gnome-sesssion` and choosing it in GDM, the switch under "Privacy" in the settings panel for the Screen Lock won't work.

The screen will still lock when the computer resumes from suspend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a flag called `ubuntu-lock-on-suspend` in dconf.

You can do it two different ways:

1. this command run in the terminal will set the flag for you:
   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false`
2. or you can install `dconf-editor` navigate to `org/gnome/desktop/screensaver` and flip the switch for `ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`.